# Powershell to list Windows network adapters marked as 'identifying...'

Tags: powershell

Trying to automate a network config powershell.
One of the commands sometimes returns the error "unable to set networkcategory on a network marked 'identifying...'. please wait for network identification to complete."

Need a way with Powershell to identify if a Windows network adapter is marked as 'identifying...' so I can ignore these adapters till identification is complete.

Get-NetAdapter does not seem to return a property that would indicate if an adapter is marked as 'identifying...'

Comment: Please post your code, along with the exact error. In simple terms, write your code so that it handles this error rather than try to "identify" such NICs

Comment: What is the `status` reported from `Get-NetAdapter` for those stated as `Identifying...`. May be check if any of those states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-networkadapter#:~:text=in%20WMI.-,Status,-Data%20type%3A) are reported and handle it accordingly.